# How to parse XML string (not file) in PIG (without load)

Tags: regex, xml, hadoop, xpath, apache-pig

I haven't found any approach to parse string with whole XML doc into separate tuples, pls suggest me how can I do this?

> Suppose we have avro file:

```
{fieldname: id, fieldname: xml}
```

> Xml structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<response>
    <name>Ghty</name>
    <main>
        <data>
            <id>1</id>
            <text>ABC mask</text>
            <title>Some text</title>
        </data>
        <data>
            <id>2</id>
            <text>Second value</text>
            <title>To</title>
        </data>
        <data>
            <id>3</id>
            <text>Evolving to</text>
            <title>Hint 567</title>
        </data>
    </main>
</response>
```

> When we do a load from **xml file**, its clear that input xml splits
>   into parts, according to the tag we put into statement:

```
DEFINE XMLLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('data');
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();
xml = LOAD '$XPATH' using XMLLoader as (x:chararray);
DUMP xml;

(<data><id>1</id><text>ABC mask</text><title>Some text</title></data>)
(<data><id>2</id><text>Second value</text><title>To</title></data>)
(<data><id>3</id><text>Evolving to</text><title>Hint 567</title></data>)

xml_parse = FOREACH xml GENERATE
    XPath(x, 'data/id') as (id:chararray), 
    XPath(x, 'data/text') as (text:chararray), 
    XPath(x, 'data/title') as (title:chararray);

DUMP xml_parse;

(1,ABC mask,Some text)
(2,Second value,To)
(3,Evolving to,Hint 567)
```

> I want to do the same with the xml in the string, **without LOAD**
>   operation. But how can we do the same if we have such xmls in a
>   **string** and they are **not splited** for further **XPath** action?

```
(<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><response><name>Ghty</name><main><data><id>1</id><text>ABC mask</text><title>Some text</title></data><data><id>2</id><text>Second value</text><title>To</title></data><data><id>3</id><text>Evolving to</text><title>Hint 567</title></data></main></response>)
```

> **1.** I tried to apply this approach, but haven't got any success, because I'm getting only the **first element from xml** string:

```
xml = LOAD 'xml_set.avro' using  
org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();

xml_parse = foreach xml generate
    XPath($0, 'data');

DUMP xml_parse ;

(1,ABC mask,Some text)
```

> **2.** I tried to use XPathAll, but haven't got success as well, all values was put in **one tuple**:

xml = LOAD 'xml_set.avro' using
    org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();

```
xml_parse = foreach xml generate
    XPathAll($0, 'data'),
    XPathAll($0, 'data'),
    XPathAll($0, 'data'),
DUMP xml_parse ;

((1,ABC mask,Some text,2,Second value,To,3,Evolving to,Hint 567))
```

> **3.** Then I tried to use XPathAll with full tag paths, but result was a **tuple of tuples**. I need somehow to split them in a right order,
>   but don't know how.

```
xml = LOAD 'xml_set.avro' using  
org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();

xml_parse = foreach xml generate
    XPathAll($0, 'data/id'),
    XPathAll($0, 'data/text'),
    XPathAll($0, 'data/title'),
DUMP xml_parse ;

((1,2,3),(ABC mask,Second value, Evolving to),(Some text,To,Hint 567))
```

> Seems need some kind of pivot to be done here. The goal is to get:

```
(1,ABC mask,Some text)
(2,Second value,To)
(3,Evolving to,Hint 567)
```

Ofc I can store all xmls from avro to 1 big xml file and then load it with XMLLoader, but its redundunt step I assume.

Appreciate any help and suggestions. Stuck with it for a long time (((

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I don't need to parse html, using regexp